# Google Charts API into Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, google-visualization

I try for a while to render a graph into my sencha touch 2 app, however I cant do it, the sencha charts is not compatible right now wit ST2. so I search and exist many APIS for make a graph, now the problem is integrate this apis into sencha touch.

I see the google charts api and is very simply, but how I can show it? i need something like a view for html.

there is a simply code: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

how I can show these code into this:

```
this.getHistorial().push({ // Is a new view in a Ext.navigation.View

                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: record.get('title'),
                        layout: 'fit',
                        htmlContent: true,

                        items: [
                            {
                                html:[ 
                                    //Show chart (Google API)
                                ].join('')
                            }
                        ]                   

                });
```

Maybe if I can make that into the html: [ ] show a little file html (like a website) and just render my app. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this discussion out: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?139473-Google-Charts-on-Sencha-Touch

It happened before ST2, but works just fine for this new release.

The main points are:
- load the google api script in your index.html
- create a panel
- pass the panel to the chart api. remember that a panel is just a propped up div

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCharts for Sencha Touch 2.x or ExtJS 4.x

There are two example applications in the GitHub repo and it is well documented.

https://github.com/woodenconsulting/OpenCharts-For-Sencha-Touch-and-ExtJS